# Problem with Adobe installation

Tags: flash, adobe

I searched for Adobe Flash Player in App Center then clicked on Install button. The Installation failed and I received this massage:

```
flashplugin-installer: Depends: libnspr4-0d but it cannot be installed.
```

I'm new to Ubuntu. Please help me.
Many thanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

Run the below command on terminal to install libnspr4-0d,

```
sudo apt-get install libnspr4-0d
```

Then open the software center and install flashplugin-installer.